# Optimize the Buddhabrot

Tags: multithreading, c++11, fractals, stdthread

I am currently working on my own implementation of the Buddhabrot. So far I am using the `std::thread`-Class from C++11 to concurrently work through the following iteration:

```
void iterate(float *res){
//generate starting point
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(-1.5,1.5);

double ReC,ImC;
double ReS,ImS,ReS_;
unsigned int steps;

unsigned int visitedPos[maxCalcIter];

unsigned int succSamples(0);

//iterate over it
while(succSamples < samplesPerThread){
    steps = 0;
    ReC = distribution(generator)-0.4;
    ImC = distribution(generator);
    double p(sqrt((ReC-0.25)*(ReC-0.25) + ImC*ImC));
    while (( ((ReC+1)*(ReC+1) + ImC*ImC) < 0.0625) || (ReC < p - 2*p*p + 0.25)){
        ReC = distribution(generator)-0.4;
        ImC = distribution(generator);
        p = sqrt((ReC-0.25)*(ReC-0.25) + ImC*ImC);
    }
    ReS = ReC;
    ImS = ImC;
    for (unsigned int j = maxCalcIter; (ReS*ReS + ImS*ImS < 4)&&(j--); ){
        ReS_ = ReS;
        ReS *= ReS;
        ReS += ReC - ImS*ImS;
        ImS *= 2*ReS_;
        ImS += ImC;
        if ((ReS+0.5)*(ReS+0.5) + ImS*ImS < 4){
            visitedPos[steps] = int((ReS+2.5)*0.25*outputSize)*outputSize + int((ImS+2)*0.25*outputSize);

        }
        steps++;

    }
    if ((steps > minCalcIter)&&(ReS*ReS + ImS*ImS > 4)){
        succSamples++;
        for (int j = steps; j--;){
            //std::cout << visitedPos[j] << std::endl;
            res[visitedPos[j]]++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So basically I am working in every thread so long that I generated enough trajectories of sufficient length which in expectation takes the same time in every thread.

But I really have the feeling that this function might me very unoptimized since its code is so very readable. Can anybody come up with some fancy optimizations? When it comes to compiling I just use:
`g++ -O4 -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/OpenEXR/ -L/usr/lib64/ -lHalf -lIlmImf -lm buddha_cpu.cpp -o buddha_cpu`

So any hints on crunching some more numbers/sec would be really appreciated. Also any links to further literature are totally welcome.

Comment: Is it fast enough for what you need? If yes, then readable code is infinitely preferable.

Comment: So, your idea of "optimized code" is equivalent to "unreadable code"? Good code should be readable, even if it's been optimized, unless you're working on a submission for one of the various Obfuscated Code Contests...

Comment: @twalberg: What I meant was, that this current approach seems rather naive and mostly follows the first implementation that comes to ones mind.

Comment: @AndyG: It is more for educational purposes that I would like to optimize this code. The speed alone is enough for getting the job done, but I would like to learn something from some hopefully helpful suggestions.

Comment: @Labello: You may have more luck at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that `-O4` is faster than `-O2`? Above O2, it's not sure.
Also, if this compilation is only for you, try `-march=native`. This will take advantage of your specific CPU architecture, but the resulting binary might crash with SIGSEV on older/different machines.

You did not show any threads, if I see correctly. Make sure your threads do not write memory locations of the same cache line. Writing memory locations in the same cache line from different threads force the CPU cores to synchronize their cache -- it's a huge performance degradation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "same cache line"? In the last for-loop all the visited points are incremented in the resulting image. This image is stored in a pointer that it shared between the different threads.

Comment: Labello: it seems like sharing. Avoid threads writing the same memory. (If they do, they should be synchronized, anyway)